# How to expose resource in devise to another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im trying to render the default devise edit registrations view in a modal. The modal is being called from another controller.. Home_controller in this case.

I have <%= render :template, 'devise/registrations/edit' %> in my modal tag and it is being called when the launch modal button is clicked but rails is through me a undefined variable method in regards to devises use of resource.
I know resource is just a user object but the home conroller does not know how to resolve this, i thought the render template method  resolves this letting rails use the devise registrations controller.

Any ideas? Im really eanting to keep the deafault devise controller to simplify future features?
How does one call a view from a different controller in one controller allowing thuse of all the actions in the called controller being available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding this to application_helper.rb (from [The Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app))

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I must have gone over the Devise wiki missing that entry dozens of times.

Comment: How can I achieve this if I have multiple resources?. One for customer and one for admin for example. Regards.