# Devise: How to move a sign in form to your homepage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, erb

In my views/devise/sessions/new.erb.html file I have the following line

```
> <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>
> session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "form-horizontal
> well"}) do |f| %>
```

This works fine, but if I try to put this form on my homepage, I get an error...

```
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x2950e78>:0x563118>
```

What do I need to do to get this working?  Or is there documentation for [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) regarding this?

Comment: I think I may have found it - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Comment: This is a duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079079/how-to-put-a-login-form-in-the-header-for-devise-and-rails?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise takes a bit of an agnostic approach to the objects it authenticates, `resource` is just a proxy for the mappings you define using the `devise_for` in your routes file. That said, if you already know the name of the resource you can just specify it manually, a la:

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => user_session_path, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal well"}) do |f|%>
```

Alternatively, you can simply define the respective `resource` and `resource_name` methods inside of your controller as shown in the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the Devise helper methods to your controller_helper.rb.  for the home controller I believe it is application_helper.rb.

An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463874/how-to-expose-resource-in-devise-to-another-controller)